Lexical error when attempting to transform JSON data retrieved from API to R object with jsonlite
I'm trying to practice retrieving data via an API into R for analysis. I'm following the tutorial here: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/r-api-tutorial/, but the URL it references for the ISS API appears to be defunct. However, I found a replacement here: http://open-notify.org/Open-Notify-API/. I keep receiving a lexical error when I try to actually convert the JSON to R data.
I've tried:
library(pacman)
p_load(
  tidyverse
  ,janitor
  ,usethis
  ,httr
  ,jsonlite)

res = GET("http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json?callback=?")
rawToChar(res$content)
data = rawToChar(res$content) %>% fromJSON()
names(data)

which produces the error,
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
                                       ?({"people": [{"craft": "ISS", 
                     (right here) ------^

Calling rawToChar(res$content) gives
[1] "?({\"people\": [{\"craft\": \"ISS\", \"name\": \"Oleg Kononenko\"}, {\"craft\": \"ISS\", \"name\": \"Nikolai Chub\"}, {\"craft\": \"ISS\", \"name\": \"Tracy Caldwell Dyson\"}, {\"craft\": \"ISS\", \"name\": \"Matthew Dominick\"}, {\"craft\": \"ISS\", \"name\": \"Michael Barratt\"}, {\"craft\": \"ISS\", \"name\": \"Jeanette Epps\"}, {\"craft\": \"ISS\", \"name\": \"Alexander Grebenkin\"}, {\"craft\": \"ISS\", \"name\": \"Butch Wilmore\"}, {\"craft\": \"ISS\", \"name\": \"Sunita Williams\"}, {\"craft\": \"Tiangong\", \"name\": \"Li Guangsu\"}, {\"craft\": \"Tiangong\", \"name\": \"Li Cong\"}, {\"craft\": \"Tiangong\", \"name\": \"Ye Guangfu\"}], \"number\": 12, \"message\": \"success\"})"

so I know the data is actually being retrieved.
I've attempted to clean up the string by removing the question mark in the string produced by rawToChar(res$content) with
data = 
  rawToChar(res$content) %>% 
  str_replace_all(.,'?','') %>% 
  fromJSON()

but that produces
Error in stri_replace_all_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  : 
  Syntax error in regex pattern. (U_REGEX_RULE_SYNTAX, context=`?`)

I also tried removing the parentheses in case that was the issue
data = 
  rawToChar(res$content) %>% 
  str_replace_all(.,'(','') %>% 
  str_replace_all(.,')','') %>% 
  fromJSON()

but got
Error in stri_replace_first_regex(string, pattern, fix_replacement(replacement),  : 
  Incorrectly nested parentheses in regex pattern. (U_REGEX_MISMATCHED_PAREN, context=`(`)

I'm at a loss.

For proper JSON response try without callback, i.e. http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json. Source: http://open-notify.org/Open-Notify-API/People-In-Space/ . BTW, while httr is not going anywhere any time soon, it is superceded by httr2, I'd personally focus on that. And judging from the linked blog post, it might be better  to start with package docs / Vignettes - https://httr2.r-lib.org/index.html

That did it! Thank you @margusl. I'd be glad to accept your comment as an answer if you repost it as such. can I ask what the "callback" piece was doing that was screwing things up?

According to http://open-notify.org/Open-Notify-API/People-In-Space/, including callback in your request makes it respond with a JSONP instead of a regular JSON .
Try with http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json:
library(httr)
GET("http://api.open-notify.org/astros.json") |> 
  content() |> 
  str()
#> List of 3
#>  $ people :List of 12
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ craft: chr "ISS"
#>   .. ..$ name : chr "Oleg Kononenko"
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ craft: chr "ISS"
#>   .. ..$ name : chr "Nikolai Chub"
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ craft: chr "ISS"
#>   .. ..$ name : chr "Tracy Caldwell Dyson"
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ craft: chr "ISS"
#>   .. ..$ name : chr "Matthew Dominick"
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ craft: chr "ISS"
#>   .. ..$ name : chr "Michael Barratt"
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ craft: chr "ISS"
#>   .. ..$ name : chr "Jeanette Epps"
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ craft: chr "ISS"
#>   .. ..$ name : chr "Alexander Grebenkin"
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ craft: chr "ISS"
#>   .. ..$ name : chr "Butch Wilmore"
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ craft: chr "ISS"
#>   .. ..$ name : chr "Sunita Williams"
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ craft: chr "Tiangong"
#>   .. ..$ name : chr "Li Guangsu"
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ craft: chr "Tiangong"
#>   .. ..$ name : chr "Li Cong"
#>   ..$ :List of 2
#>   .. ..$ craft: chr "Tiangong"
#>   .. ..$ name : chr "Ye Guangfu"
#>  $ number : int 12
#>  $ message: chr "success"


Regarding issues you had during string cleaning, stringr generally expects to receive a regular expression for the pattern argument and ? happens to carry a special meaning in regex. To match a literal ?, you would need to escape it with \\ or change its meaning with
fixed() or coll():
library(stringr)
str_remove_all('?({"people" ...', '\\?')
#> [1] "({\"people\" ..."
str_remove_all('?({"people" ...', fixed('?'))
#> [1] "({\"people\" ..."

